# How to get cell values from datagridview title row?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to extract Data grid view's title Row (Header row) values , How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Hint: `DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

From the first google search i found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use the following code:

```
string s = dataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText;
```

Try to search before asking here. Others might have had the same question you are facing.

Comment: Was this answer useful or not?